# Why isn't my if condition always executing and not the elif or else condition?

Tags: python, if-statement

I can't get my head around this particular `if..else` statement:

```
print("Do you want to run the next bit of code? Y/N")
n = input()

if n == "Y" or "y":
    j = [12, 43, 54, 65]
    for i in j:
        print (i, end="" "\t")

elif n == "N" or "n":
    print("You get numbers if you had pressed Y")

else:
    print("That's not an option")
```

My problem here is, whatever the value I give for `n`, it always gives me the output of `Y` or `y`. I always get the output as the array numbers. Which means that my condition is not working. So what is actually the problem with the first condition?

Comment: you need to do `if n == "Y" or n == "y"`  otherwise "y" evaluates always to True. Alternatively you can do something like: `if n in ("Y", "y")` which is more compact and allows you to put a large number of characters to be checked

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki any particular reason why you used a tuple? It works equally well with a list. Thanks.

Comment: you can write if n.lower() =="y" and same for elif condition.
it will work

Comment: @Neeraj no particular reason. A list works also fine, both options are correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20002503/why-does-a-b-or-c-or-d-always-evaluate-to-true?noredirect=1&lq=1). 
The following code works.

```
print("Do you want to run the next bit of code? Y/N")
n = input()
if n in ["Y", "y"]:
    j = [12, 43, 54, 65]
    for i in j:
        print (i, end="" "\t")
elif n in ["N", "n"]:
    print("You get numbers if you had pressed Y")
else:
    print("That's not an option")
```